# Does multiple characteristics increase BLE throughput

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, btle

I am sending data via BLE between an Android phone and an embedded device. I was able to increase the throughput by modifying the connection interval. Is there any difference(data rate) between sending large data packets through single characteristics or multiple characteristics?

As shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24144483/29941

Comment: any updates on this question?

Comment: @IdoRan - the number of characteristics the data is split across does not effect the overall throughput.