# Reading More then 20 byte from remote BLE device failed in Lollipop

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are facing one issue when reading characteristics from remote BLE device.

This issue happen in `Android OS 5.0` and above.

Points are below to generate issue :

> 1. Make one peripheral device with one service and one characteristics.
> 2. Characteristics will have only read permission. Now set the value of this characteristics with more than 20 characters i.e. 20 bytes.
> 3. Now let peripheral device broadcast itself with one service and one characteristics.
> 4. Now launch any BLE scanner app from market  and connect with this peripheral device.
> 5. Once successfully connected with peripheral device just try to read characteristics.
> 6. In this case it will not show any data and when debugging the app it show that it returns null data.
> 7. The above same case not working in the Android OS 5.0 and above.
> 8. Same case working in android 4.4.

So there is something change in Android OS 5.0 and above that internally disable `readblob()` request that can read data having more that 20 characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135682/android-sending-data-20-bytes-by-ble

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achievable by splitting your data into 20 byte packets and implementing a short delay (i.e. using sleep()) between sending each packet.

You can use `BluetoothGatt.requestMtu()`. See the [Official document of   BluetoothGatt.requestMtu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestMtu(int))

```
     Request an MTU size used for a given connection. 
       When performing a write request operation (write without response), the data       
sent is truncated to the MTU size. This function may be used to request a larger MTU size to be able to send more data at once.

A onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt, int, int) callback will indicate whether this operation was successful.

Requires BLUETOOTH permission.
```

If you want send more 20 bytes, you should define array byte[] include how many packet you want.
There is an example [Android: Sending data >20 bytes by BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135682/android-sending-data-20-bytes-by-ble)

Also there is another example [How to send more than 20 bytes data over ble in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130162/how-to-send-more-than-20-bytes-data-over-ble-in-android?lq=1)