# The data length in BluetoothGattServer.sendResponse can't exceed 20 bytes. (BLE)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I've tried the BLE GATT Peripheral running on Nexus 6 based on the work of [g-ortuno](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/ble-test-peripheral-android), and it works fine, but sendResponse method can't send data larger than 20 bytes.
And found the same problem for writeCharacteristic, its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24178409/5121651) doesn't work for me. Does anyone meet the same problem and know the possible solution for this? Thanks.