# Android: BLE device is sending packet time is slow and get only max 20 byte at a time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am developing health application so use BLE device(Hardware).

1. From BLE Device send 25 byte at one packet but on mobile(Android)
   side we receive 20 byte. (I am refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135682/android-sending-data-20-bytes-by-ble))
2. When receiving each packet send acknowledgement to BLE device. But we
   this process is very slow. and we can't get packet in particular
   time.
3. We require 500 packet in 1 second. But get only 10 Packet in 1
   second.
4. Main problem is not getting packets as per as requirement.

So please tell me is BLE send packet as faster as my requirement or if not then i am using again Bluetooth?

Please suggest me tutorial to get data faster from BLE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting [requestConnectionPriority](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestConnectionPriority(int)) to `CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH`