# How do I broadcast 47 Byte Bluetooth payload using BLE4.0 module?

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm able to advertise 32 Byte of data using Bluetooth Low Energy csr4.0 module to the nearest Android device and I used `hcitool -i cmd Proximity UUID major and minor` to broadcast, but using same command I'm unable to advertise 47 Byte of data and it should modify the BLE module end, which is connected to laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Sending data >20 bytes by BLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135682/android-sending-data-20-bytes-by-ble)

Answer (score 0):

Per Core_v4.0 specification document, in 6.B.2.3.1.1, AdvData is limited to 31 bytes. You may add 31 more bytes of advertisement data in the scan response packet, but this necessitates active scanning from the scanner.

So you may have 62 total bytes of AD, 31 of which are broadcasted and seen by passive scanners, and 31 other that are visible to active scanners.

You may split the 31 bytes as you want for multiple AD records, but one AD record may not span across ADV_IND and SCAN_RSP. Note some AD records are forbidden in SCAN_RSP and need to be in ADV_IND. See [CSS v6](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=302735) for defined AD types.