# How can Android BLE read more than 20 bytes, requestMtu() is not working?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to use Android BLE to receive more than 20 bytes one package, but it does not work. So I tried `BluetoothGatt.requestMtu()`. It returns true, but is not working. I know the MTU exchange request can only be initialized by client, that is an Android phone. I do not understand why this API is not working.
The phone I use is an OnePlus 6 with Android 8.1

Comment: To what are you setting the MTU? Too high values will always fail. 
That method will always return true if you have a connection, but real success is only when you get a call to onMtuChange: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onMtuChanged(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)
Your phone is sure capable of MTUs of at least 200 (tested with mine) but still you need the other device to be capable of that too

Comment: BLE is only for a small amount of data. So you had to split the 20 Bytes or use classic Bluetooth

Comment: onMtuChange also returns true. I also use iphone X to test longer mtu, it works well because it initialized the mtu exchange request.

Answer (score 2):

It is not related to Android framework API. It belongs to Bluetooth BLE specification.
Please check more details here. 
[Maximum packet length for Bluetooth LE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913743/maximum-packet-length-for-bluetooth-le)