# Android BLE transmission interupted by next line

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an Android app that needs to send data from an accelerometer to an arduino. The problem is that the string is sent only half-way moment at which the next transmission starts. Anything I tried like SystemClock.sleep(); did not help, meaning that any next line would interrupt the transmission of the string.

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        acceler[0]=event.values[0];
        acceler[1]=event.values[1];
        acceler[2]=event.values[2];
        transmit();
    }

    private void transmit() {
        String str =":" + acceler[0] + " " + acceler[1] + " " + acceler[2] + "\n\r";
        final byte[] tx = str.getBytes();
        if(mConnected) {
            TXcharact.setValue(tx);
            mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(TXcharact);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on BLE specification, but your str seems too long to send at once.

[Maximum packet length for Bluetooth LE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913743/maximum-packet-length-for-bluetooth-le)

> "BLE allow you transfer maximum is 20 bytes."
>
> "You are correct that the BLE specification doesn't allow write operations to exceed 20 bytes."

So, split them and use some waiting queue to store them.