# Not getting all bytes from beak callback on notify

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using [bleak](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to connect to a GATT server and gather packets transmitted from a peripheral.  The server is set up using notifications, so I am registering a callback with the function `start_notify` to capture those bytes produced by the characteristic and log them.  The characteristic that is handled by this particular callback sends 200 bytes at regular intervals.  I am able to

- connect to the server
- start notifications for this characteristics
- and collect data from this characteristic on notification

However, it seems that I am only collecting a fraction on the bytes that are available. The call to start notifications looks like

```
await self.client.start_notify(self.data, self.data_notification_cb, )
```

and the actual call back looks like

```
    def data_notification_cb(self, sender: str, data: str):
        hdata = binascii.hexlify(data)
        print("Current data value is %s" % hdata)
        self.write_voice.write(hdata)
```

The data produced by the server looks like

```
b8 5b 2e 64 ab 77 5e d3 05 08 27 39 8e 9d 3d 2a
e1 0d bf 3c bf 19 5f 44 05 86 e7 35 98 22 a7 9f
cc e1 aa 4d 5b b4 5e 5b b2 91 e8 98 8e 0f 38 92
78 b9 90 0f 2b 62 e7 5f 56 e8 83 83 65 e8 56 32
81 48 85 11 cc cd c3 a6 e8 6b 49 d9 77 b4 b4 34
b7 87 f2 eb 9c 05 7e 65 52 36 98 20 b2 9b 64 d8
fc d2 92 e1 cd fd f5 e5 81 9a 97 5b a9 f0 98 6c
6b ca 08 0c 77 19 34 4d 93 25 8e 5a 31 a9 9f a7
53 fd 7a 1e b7 97 44 e5 d4 25 02 42 04 b6 e0 7b
06 b7 ea 96 77 7b 0f 8c 63 ca 7e bd 3e 52 a1 a0
82 50 29 dc 6b 0e 3a 1d 68 92 21 88 0c b7 54 b8
8c f3 16 ed 4b 78 3c a3 2d 78 ba 09 b3 25 d1 c9
ec af 0c d9 7a 0d a9 b1
```

while the data that is returned by the call back is truncated like so

```
b'b85b2e64ab775ed3050827398e9d3d2ae10dbf3c'
```

so that at most it gives back 19 bytes.  Has anyone seen this before?  Am I misconfiguring this callback so that it only gets a subset of the available bytes?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the BLE adapter of the device you are running your script on (probably a Notebook) is only capable of BLE 4.0. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38914831/7473793) answer BLE 4.0 only supports up to 20 bytes per notification.

You could use a different device thats capable of a higher BLE version to check if everything else works. I recommend the [nRF Connect App](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) for your mobile device.

If everything works on your mobile device the use of a USB BLE adapter could help you achieve your goals.

Comment: Sigh...that is an excellent point.  I forgot about the DLE so the MTU negotiated is likely much smaller than what I am requesting.  Luckily this is not a laptop and I have access to multiple BT radios running different version of BT.  Just to be clear, the DLE was active with 4.2, not just 5 compliant stacks.

Comment: You can also get a BLE 5.0 dongle, this way you dont have to switch device (notebook). bleuio works really well for me

Comment: OK...so this is actually not the issue.  Controller config indicates that the controller is that the stack is 5.0.

Comment: Have you tried the nRF Connect app? This would help to pinpoint the source of the problem. If it does not work with the app the peripheral is at fault.