# Android BLE - How to calculate AdvertiseData's size (overall and by components)?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm advertising an Android device over Bluetooth Low Energy with the below code:

```
private void advertise() {
    BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

    AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
            .setConnectable(false)
            .build();

    ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(getString(R.string.ble_uuid)));

    byte[] messageToSend = "Data".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .addServiceUuid(pUuid)
            .addServiceData(pUuid, messageToSend)
            .build();

    AdvertiseCallback advertisingCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
            Log.d("Successful", "start");
            super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
            Log.e("BLE", "Advertising onStartFailure: " + errorCode);
            super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
        }
    };

    advertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, advertisingCallback);
}
```

The plan is this: send a message (in this case *"Data"*) to every BLE-compatible device nearby with Bluetooth turned on with advertising. I've tested it, and the other device received the *"Data"* string successfully in the `AdvertiseData` object. But as I know there are limitations of this approach (maybe I'm wrong on any of the next points, please feel free to correct me ;) ):

- The total size of the advertising data (`AdvertiseData` object) can be maximum 32 bytes
- From this structure 20 bytes can be used to send custom advertising data

If I understand correctly the last point, it means that I can send 20 ASCII characters encoded by UTF-8 with one `AdvertiseData` object (I would like to approach this situation similar to the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135682/android-sending-data-20-bytes-by-ble) question to send more than 20 bytes). However, currently I can send up to 9 ASCII characters - if I want to send one more, the callback's `onStartFailure()` method is returning with `errorCode` 1 (`ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE` according to [the documentation of AdvertiseCallback class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseCallback.html#ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE)). Of course this 'limit' is even smaller when I'm using non-ASCII characters (for example accented characters - `é`, `ű`, and so on)...

It is possible that my approach is not the best, because I've found different examples on the web to send advertising data... so maybe I'm constructing the `AdvertiseData` object with some unnecessary object which are occupying free space in data. So basically I would like to find out:

1. How many bytes is the size of the `AdvertiseData` object?
2. How is this object splitted? What are the parts which I have to think about during calculation, and how big are they?

Could you help me in my experiment? :D

---

My AdvertiseData object looks like this:

```
AdvertiseData 
  [mServiceUuids=
    [bdc7950d-731f-4d4d-8e47-c090502dbd63], 
  mManufacturerSpecificData={}, 
  mServiceData=
    {bdc7950d-731f-4d4d-8e47-c090502dbd63=[68, 97, 116, 97]}, 
  mIncludeTxPowerLevel=false,
  mIncludeDeviceName=false]
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? To me, it returns the error with just one letter.... I don't know what's going to happen, I'm pretty lost.