# Receiving only 20 Characters from BLE instead of whole JSON

Tags: json, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

im receiving only 20 Characters of my JSON and dont know why. Other Applications are able to show the Whole Json but my Code cuts it down after the 20th Character.

I dont know what to improve to get the whole JSON. Buffering doesnt work for me as it only puts all the cut down Snippets together instead of the whole JSON

this is the Code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'widgets/ble.dart'; // Import your BLE data class

import 'dart:math';

class TemperaturChartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TemperaturChartPageState createState() => _TemperaturChartPageState();
}

final characteristicUuid = "19B10021-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214";
final globalBluetoothData = GlobalBluetoothData();
final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();

class _TemperaturChartPageState extends State<TemperaturChartPage> {
  final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();
  StreamSubscription<List<int>>? _bleSubscription;
  String jsonData = ''; // Variable to hold JSON data

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subscribeToTemperatureCharacteristic();
  }

  void _subscribeToTemperatureCharacteristic() {
    // Use the characteristic UUID from WaermeScreen

    if (globalBluetoothData.connectedDeviceId != null &&
        globalBluetoothData.serviceUuid != null) {
      final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
          serviceId: Uuid.parse(globalBluetoothData.serviceUuid!),
          characteristicId: Uuid.parse(characteristicUuid),
          deviceId: globalBluetoothData.connectedDeviceId!);

      _bleSubscription = flutterReactiveBle
          .subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristic)
          .listen((data) {
        setState(() {
          jsonData = utf8.decode(data); // Decode the incoming data
        });
      }, onError: (dynamic error) {
        print("Error receiving data from BLE device: $error");
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Temperature Chart"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(jsonData), // Display the prefixed JSON data
            ),
            // Add other widgets or charts as needed
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bleSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Buffering, i thought maybe packages are sent that needs to be received first but i was only "pulling" 20 Characters everytime

Comment: You probably need to request a higher MTU. Read this question and answers for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135682/android-sending-data-20-bytes-by-ble