# Sending more than 20 bytes through BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to send a json string over BLE, but, like the json has more than 20 bytes, I've to send multiple packets of 20 bytes.

I've read all posts that I've found. Some examples:

- [Android: Sending data >20 bytes by BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135682/android-sending-data-20-bytes-by-ble)
- [Android 4.4 BLE indication data more than 20 byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054594/android-4-4-ble-indication-data-more-than-20-byte)
- https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/155/writing-more-than-20-bytes-at-a-time-to-a-characteristic/
- https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/12416/android-sending-data-20-bytes-by-ble/

All posts contain similar information. In the first post are implemented some functions, but:

- What are "BLE.INITIAL_MESSAGE_PACKET" and  BLE.DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET" variables? where is the declaration of each one?
- Where is the "sendingLastPacket(characteristic, initial_packet, CHARACTERS)" function?
- On the receptor side, how can I merge all packets that the transmitter has sent?

I haven't found any information about this problemas.. can anyone help me?

Comment: Why don't you ask the guy who posted the code?

Comment: Because other users have already asked and anyone has answered =(

Comment: From what side do you want to send data from? An android phone? A nordic semiconductor-device?